# React Native iOS release build fails in azure pipeline

Tags: ios, azure, react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Recently upgraded to node 18 and use node 18 in the pipeline.

Running

npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release --verbose

fails with the following error.

Worth noting, I'm using zsh locally but in pipeline it seems to pick run bash.

```
debug Reading /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Podfile
debug Reading /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Podfile.lock
info Found Xcode workspace "Myapp.xcworkspace"
info Launching iPhone 13 (iOS 15.2)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace Myapp.xcworkspace -configuration Release -scheme Myapp -destination id=D82A8073-48E0-404F-9A66-2D4EE2EDEFC7")
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Myapp.xcworkspace.
##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/bin/bash'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/bin/bash'
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]
Finishing: iOS Build
```

Answer (score 0):

You can periodically clean DerivedData  folder with the following command:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

And run your command again to check if the issue could be resolved.

```
npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release --verbose
```